# Converting a const function to a component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert this line of code to a component. This line of code works:

```
const GlobalCss = withStyles(s)(() => null);
export default GlobalCss;
```

This is what it looks like as a component:

```
const GlobalCss = function(props){
    return withStyles(props.css)(() => null);
}
```

But this compiles with the error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related with `material-ui` `withStyle` HOC's issue

For your code

```
const App = function(props){
    return withStyles()(() => null);
}
```

Is the same as the below `arrow function version`

```
const App = props => withStyles()(() => null); // Nop
```

And this works

```
const App = withStyles()(() => null); // OK
```

So if you need `props` been defined, use it inside the style related HOC seems fine.

```
const App = withStyles()(props => null); // OK
```

In our prod, we use other HOCs like `redux` `connect` which is related to props inside `withStyles`, too.

Sample:

```
export const ComponentName = withTheme(withStyles(styles)(connect(
  (store: Store) => ({...}), // props
  (dispatch: any) => ({...}) // props
)(YourComponent)));
```

You can try it online here

[image: Edit happy-snowflake-9t4p7]

#### Update

If the demand needs to pass `classes` done via `props`

Use `withStyles` would be good enough

```
interface Props extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  classes: any,
  ...
```

#### Update V.2

If you want to use global styles as well as `withStyles`, there is an option to make a common custom HOC behind the `withStyles`.

```
export const YourComponent = withStyles()(
  mergeGlobalStylesHOC(() => null)
);
```

#### Update V.3

And for functional component, export the global style hooks would be a good practice, also.

And if you want to custom all the material-component without writing the related style everywhere, simply reuse the customized component would be good.

Comment: I need it as a function where I can pass in props. I updated my code sample to show how props.css is included. The css is pre-loaded from an external css file before any rendering is executed. To use that css, withStyles needs to be executed inside a function (component). If you use the approaches you have shown using a const, withStyles is executed immediately when the app starts, which doesn't allow the css property to be applied.

Comment: @AndroidDev Doesn't see any necessity to pass it through all the props, since you use it globally, you can import at any time you want. And you can use `Theme` and other methods, too.

Comment: Whether I pass it through the props or use some other mechanism isn't really important. What is important is that withStyles only gets called AFTER the external css data has been loaded. The withStyles function takes those loaded styles as its first parameter. Unfortunately I don't see anything in your samples that shows how to have withStyles part of a component.

Comment: Just don't understand why you need those global styles been loaded `as the first parameter`. In my opinion, it's no need. If you need to merge local styles with global styles in every component, just write a common HOC behind the `withStyles` would be fine. And you can merge it in a way what ever you want

Comment: Lol, that's out of this question but I guess there are some demands to let them made this pattern, as well as it may be anti-pattern under some certain situation/tool-chains. By the way for functional component, hooks also seem to be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

YOU have an issue to use the HOC try  to use this shape for a higher-order component in   react 
I thank you should read about Hoc

with styles is the what you want injection inside the component as GlobalClass
    function GlobalClass(props) {
    ... //the null or as you want what is you return 
    }

```
export default withStyles(styles)(GlobalClass);
```

I think this is the same  what you want

```
(props=>null)// is equal as the function above
```

I think if used the shape it will be work tell me if it works

Comment: withStyles MUST be inside a function. If you use it as a const, it will get executed when the app runs. It must only be executed when the component is being referenced. A HOC doesn't help - at least not any I've tried.